# Multihomed Network Setup and routing

Tags: networking

I have two computers that each have two NICs on them a single router and two layer 2 switches.

**ComputerA -**

eth0 - connected to L2Switch0, connected to router (192.168.0.1)

IP: 192.168.0.224/24
GW: 192.168.0.1

eth1 - connected to L2Switch1

IP: 192.168.2.20/24

**ComputerB -**

eth0 - connected to L2Switch0, connected to router (192.168.0.1)

IP: 192.168.0.24/24
GW: 192.168.0.1

eth1 - connected to L2Switch1

IP: 192.168.2.10/24

The 192.168.0.0/24 network is routed for internet however I do not want the 192.168.2.0/24 network routed.  I want it to remain local and only be accessible on the layer 2 switch that I have both computers connected to.  I have eth1 on both computers setup with static IPs, but I am unsure of what else I need to configure to get them to be able to ping one another via the eth1 interfaces.  I can ping between the two computers via the eth0 using the 192.168.0.0/24 network, just not via the 192.168.2.0/24 network on eth1.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 and netplan to configure both interfaces.

No changes have been made to the firewall setup on either computer.

**ComputerA ip route show:**

```bsh
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static  
10.1.50.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.50.1  
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown  
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.224  
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.20
```

**ComputerB netstat -nr**

```bsh
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGS         re0
127.0.0.1          lo0                UHS         lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#5             U           re0
192.168.0.24       link#5             UHS         lo0
192.168.2.0/24     192.168.0.1        UGS         re0
192.168.2.10       link#10            UHS         lo0
```

Please let me know if there are any details I left out that need to be provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you share the output of `ip route show`. Did you make any custom setting for firewall or iptable?

Comment: Would you please edit the question and add important and requested info up there. Comments get removed sometimes.

Comment: @user.dz did you have any suggestions based on the additional details?

Comment: Seems fine, could you share the 2nd one. So you can't get `ping 192.168.2.10` to replay? I see `192.168.0.224`, not same in settings shown in the question ?

Comment: @user.dz I should mention that ComputerB is a FreeBSD box so I provided the netstat -nr results to give you the routing info and I correted the IP typos in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried ping from both computers? I'm suspecting firewall issue, probably FreeBSD (I heard about its high security measures), I'm sure Ubuntu default low ICMP pings

Comment: @user.dz I can't ping from or to either computer on the 192.168.2.0, but pings work fine using the 192.168.0.0 network.  I don't see any firewall rules on either side that would be doing anything to stop pings, or any other traffic.  Would there need to be any switch configuration that needs to be done to facilitate the traffic?  I don't have any vlans or anything setup, but I am not sure if anything is necessary.